# gotoAndPlay not working?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am very new to AS.

I have the following code that is used to go to the next frame after a sound is completed.

```
stop();
invisible_btn.enabled = false;
voice = new Sound();
voice.attachSound("introVoiceOver");
voice.start();
voice.onSoundComplete = function() {gotoAndPlay(2);
                                    main.sub1.gotoAndPlay(2);};
```

Now instead I would like it to go to the **first frame of sub2**. I changed the function with:

```
voice.onSoundComplete = function() { main.sub2.gotoAndPlay(1);};
```

But after the sound is complete it just does not do anything.
anything to help please?

Comment: Is the main instance included on the second frame of the main timeline only? Perhaps you need to include the gotoAndPlay(2) statement as well?

Comment: if I include the gotoAndPlay(2), it goes to the 2nd frame of the same sub1. I want to avoid that and go directly to sub2!

Comment: Actually, what is `sub2`? Is it a scene? If so, use `main.gotoAndPlay(1,'sub2');`

Comment: No, it is not a scene. it is a whole movie clip.. all within the same Scene!

Comment: Put a `trace` command  in the function see if it gets called. If it does, then there is something wrong with your `sub2` maybe it is not present, or named a little different.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `stop();` command in the first frame of your sub animation?
The code of a frame gets executed even if you say gotoAndPlay(). When your frame says stop() then it will stop there!

What you could do is:

- Remove the stop and handle all animation play calls from a controller/other clip
- jump to the second frame insted